# LoadRunner: Бесконечная запись событий при создании скрипта

Tags: производительность, нагрузочное-тестирование

Во время записи скрипта процесс "Recording events" не останавливается, что приводит к генерации огромного скрипта на тысячи строк даже для 1-2 действий пользователя. Для примера, на простейшее действие получаю 5-6 тысяч строк. Проблема проявляется на всех версиях начиная с 12.53 до 12.55.

Что я уже предпринял:

- Использовал различные браузеры.
- Отключал антивирус.
- Переустанавливал *Windows*.
- Пробовал запустить в *VirtualBox*.
- Испробовал различные настройки прокси в *LoadRunner*.